# filter by multiple values angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to perform the filter and get the count of the resulted rows in js file

Filter by

1) locationId and
 2) startDate between introductoryPeriodStart and introductoryPeriodEnd.

The following statement is giving synatx error. Could somebody please give me the right statement.

```
$scope.NewEmps = $filter('filter')($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, { locationId: $scope.selectedItem.Label } | { startDate:$scope.Model.introductoryPeriodStart:$scope.Model.introductoryPeriodEnd}).length;
```

Code :

```
DashBoardModule.controller('DashBoardController', ['$scope','$filter', 'DashBoardModuleService', function ($scope,$filter, DashBoardModuleService) {

    $scope.SelectedItems = {};
    $scope.NewEmps;
    $scope.Qualfd;
    $scope.Scred;
    $scope.submtd8850MisinDocs;
    $scope.DocsRecvd8850;
    $scope.DocsSubmtd8850;
    $scope.Approved;
    $scope.Denied;
    $scope.NeedMoreInfo;
    $scope.selectedItem;
var Ein = '0000000';

    DashBoardModuleService.GetDashBoardSummary(Ein).then(function (response) {
       // $scope.Summary = JSON.stringify(response.data.Summary);
        $scope.Summary = response.data.Summary;
        $scope.corporateId = response.data.Summary.corporateId;       
        $scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {
            $scope.selectedItem = item;          
        }     
        console.log($scope.Summary);
    });

    $('#txtDateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $scope.isRefreshing = true;
        $scope.Model.introductoryPeriodEnd = $filter('date')(new Date(picker.endDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
        $scope.Model.introductoryPeriodStart = $filter('date')(new Date(picker.startDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
        $scope.Model.typeAvailability = picker.chosenLabel === "Custom Range" ? "Custom" : picker.chosenLabel;
        $scope.$apply();

        console.log($scope.Model.introductoryPeriodEnd);
        console.log($scope.Model.introductoryPeriodStart);
        $scope.FilterByDate();
    });   

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var dateConfiguration = new Date();
        $('#txtDateRange').daterangepicker({
            locale:{
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
            },
            autoApply: true
        });
        loadChartCallCenter();
        loadChartHumanEfits();
        loadChartQualificationSource(362, 100, 88);
    });

    $scope.greaterThan = function (prop, val) {
        return function (item) {
            return item[prop] > val;
        }
    };

    $scope.lessThan = function (prop, val) {
        return function (item) {
            return item[prop] < val;
        }
    };

    $scope.FilterByDate = function () {
        console.log($scope.selectedItem);
        console.log($scope.selectedItem.Label);
        console.log($scope.Model.introductoryPeriodStart);
        console.log($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees);

        $scope.NewEmps = $scope.$eval("Summary.CorpEmployees | filter:{locationId:selectedItem.Label} | filter:greatherThan('startDate',Model.introductoryPeriodStart) | filter:lessThan('startDate',Model.introductoryPeriodEnd)").length;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: you dont need to use angularjs here, you can just `filter` the array using the `filter` function of the array prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You have few errors:
 0- The date (greather / less) filters are not defined.
 1-  You can't use in this way.

So:
 0- Define greatherThan

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
  return function(item){
    return item[prop] > val;
  }
};
```

1- Define lessThan

```
$scope.lessThan = function(prop, val){
  return function(item){
    return item[prop] < val;
  }
};
```

2- Use `$scope.$eval`

```
$scope.size =  $scope.$eval("elements | filter:{locationId:location} | filter:greatherThan('startDate',initDate) | filter:lessThan('startDate',endDate)").length;
```

---

I updated with a better approach. Check this:

I combine `lessThan` with `greatherThan` in a only one: `inRangeDate`. Plus, if it is not a date I will automatically cast to date.

```
$scope.inRangeDate = function (prop, init, end) {
  return function(item){
    init = init instanceof Date ? init : new Date(init);
    end = end instanceof Date ? end : new Date(end);
    return item[prop] > init && item[prop] < end;
  }
};
```

Check this Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bxPdNAUjV6I0uuJb8iRp?p=preview (I apply it on the `$scope.size`)
0. The first approach is in Version 4 of Plunkr
1. The inRangeDate approach is in Version 5 of same Plunkr

Comment: I am getting the following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Can you share your code to check if there is a problem? Did you check the Plunkr? Can you try using `$scope.$eval('elements').length`, if it works add filter by filter until got again the error.

Comment: I shared the code. The error is gone now. I change from $eval('$scope.Summary') to $eval('Summary'). But , $eval is not producing the desired results.    pasted below or two lines of code. The $filter producing the correct results but $eval is not doing any filtering.   console.log($filter('filter')($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, { locationId: $scope.selectedItem.Label }));
            console.log($scope.$eval("Summary.CorpEmployees | filter:{locationId:$scope.selectedItem.Label}"));

Comment: Ok, in the eval try this: `console.log($scope.$eval("Summary.CorpEmployees | filter:{locationId:selectedItem.Label}")); ` I removed the `$scope` suffix of  `$scope.selectedItem.Label`

Comment: @BumbleBee (I don't mention you before)

Comment: The first filter is doing what is expected but not the second and third. ie. filter:greatherThan('startDate',initDate)  and filter:lessThan('startDate',endDate).

Comment: Did you defined it?. You must add both custom functions in the $scope. As I do in the Plunkr. Did you check the Plunkr? There is working the whole code -  check the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/bxPdNAUjV6I0uuJb8iRp?p=preview

Comment: Those custom functions are added to the $scope.   Checked the plunker.

Comment: Ok share the whole code of the eval now, to check again

Comment: $scope.$eval("Summary.CorpEmployees | filter:{locationId:selectedItem.Label} | filter:greatherThan('startDate',Model.introductoryPeriodStart) | filter:lessThan('startDate',Model.introductoryPeriodEnd)").length;

Comment: Ok it look great. I really cannot find an error there.

Comment: Are u still having problem with this?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. For what ever reason, I don't know, the above code didn't work. Finally I had to use filter.     As shown below          $scope.CorpEmployeesByLocation = $filter('filter')($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, { locationId: $scope.selectedItem.Label });
                    $scope.BetweenDatesFilter = $filter('filter')($scope.CorpEmployeesByLocation, function (o) {
                        return (new Date(o.startDate) > new Date($scope.Model.DateFrom)) && (new Date(o.startDate) < new Date($scope.Model.DateTo))});

Comment: Ok, it looks pretty cool. But, I have a doubt: did you try to do the cast to date with code above? It is the only think I think it could go wrong before :D

Check again the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bxPdNAUjV6I0uuJb8iRp?p=preview  I added a inRangeDate (so will be only one filter, plus it will cast to date if is not a date provided)